# Getting un-wanted square bracket after a character in french language

Tags: html, character-encoding, ascii, character

i have fallowing sentence in french language, when i am displaying it on browser i am getting square bracket in place of this ` character.
sentence- **Méthode d’expédition**

the char after d is displaying as a square bracket.

can any one tell me or have any idea why this issue is happening.

Comment: Chances are your advertised encoding is not the one you're actually using - but it's hard to say without more information.

Comment: Please post more information, preferably a URL of a demo page. Also please specify whether you actually see a bracket “[” or a small rectangle. The latter sounds more probable—it typically indicates character data error, such as octets (bytes) that do not represent any character in the encoding that has been assumed. Probably some encoding conversion error has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

This will likely be a problem with the character encoding used for the HTML document. Ideally it should be in UTF-8.

For HTML5, add this at the top of your head element:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Or for previous versions of HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```